# CakePHP form not rendering correctly in element

Tags: forms, cakephp, element, cakephp-2.1

I am using an element to render a form. The problem is that when I include the element `echo $this->element('report', array('id' => $id, 'title' => $title));`, the form appears like:

```
<form id="BugAdminIndexForm" class="form-vertical" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/admin/stations"></form>
<div style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method">
</div>
<input id="BugType" type="hidden" value="database" name="data[Bug][type]">
...
```

So, the form is closed before all inputs are rendered.

While testing the form separately in the view (without it being included in the element), it renders correctly, with the same code (except the call to the element).

What's the reason for this?

**EDIT**

Here's the element's code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-<?php echo $id; ?>">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h3>Report bug</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Bug', array('class' => 'form-vertical')); ?>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->hidden('type', array('value' => 'database'));
            echo $this->Form->hidden('title', array('value' => $title));

            echo $title;

            echo $this->Form->input('bug', array('div' => 'control-group', 'label' => array('text' => 'Bug', 'class' => 'control-label'), 'between' => '<div class="controls">', 'after' => '</div>', 'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'), 'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline'))));
        ?>  
        <?php echo $this->Js->submit('Send', array(
            'url' => array('superuser' => true, 'controller' => 'bugs', 'action' => 'report'),
            'type' => 'json',
            'success' => '
                if(data === true){
                    $("#modal-'.$id.' .modal-body").html("thanks"); 
                } else if(data === false){
                    $("#modal-'.$id.' .modal-body").html("error");  
                } else {
                    $.each(data, function(field, error){
                        $input = $("#modal-'.$id.' .modal-body #Bug" + field.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + field.slice(1));
                        $input.after("<p class=\"help-block\">" + error + "</span>");
                        $input.closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
                    }); 
                }
            ',
            'div' => false
        )); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

Comment: what's the code of your element `report.ctp` file?

Comment: You're going to need to post the element's code - it's gotta be something pretty simple in the element.

Comment: I've posted the element's code. I believe it's something small, but can't figure it out...

Comment: Weird , From where that `<div style="display:none;">` line showed up?

Comment: It contains a hidden input Cake generates. I edited the question now.

Comment: I would try dropping all the excess stuff, getting it down to it's core (without the JS...etc)- test that, and if still doesn't work, just post that.

Comment: The thing is that, all the code from the element, when pasted in the actual view, works as expected, so I believe there nothing wrong in the element's code...

Comment: Not the point - the point is to not waste people's time who are hoping to help by having excess and unrelated code they'd need to wade through.

Comment: Ofir asked for the element's code, that's why I've added it to my question :)

Comment: @linkyndy - was just trying to help you get an answer - apparently you don't want one

Comment: I know, but he was also trying to help when asking for the code, so I don't know what is wrong :) Anyway, I can't get why isn't the form rendered correctly since it is the same code...

Comment: No reason for me to continue to argue - if you'd like more/faster help, do a bit of your own testing and narrow it down to the code that's actually related to the issue.  GL.

Comment: I had the same problem, but instead of calling an element, it was within my view itself. In my case, I was calling the form create between two <tr> elements, so not a valid location. I moved my create to just above my <table> tag and my close to just below the correspondig </table>

Answer (score 1):

Change your element to the following to see if it appears correctly:

```
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php 
        echo $this->Form->create('Bug');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('type', array('value' => 'database'));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('title', array('value' => $title));
        echo $this->Form->input('bug');
        echo $this->Form->end('Submit'); 
    ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
</div>
```

Comment: I needed AJAX functionality, that's why I couldn't use the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in a view and the comment added by Brett F helped me.

My create was included inside a table. I moved both Form->create and Form->end just before and after the table respectively and everything worked as expected.

The credits for this answers should go to him.

In my case, CakePHP 3.2.7